Visio Diagram with Transparent Background looks wrong in Powerpoint
I know how to make the diagram in Visio have a transparent background. I go to File > Export, then save as a .png and tick the box to enable transparency.
But when I insert that png image in to a Power point presentation on to a slide with a colored background then the Cause and Effect diagram looks terrible and blurry.
How can I make the diagram appear sharp like it appears in Visio but with a transparent background so it look good on the Powerpoint presentation?
Any help much appreciated.


Try saving as SVG or EMF, not PNG -- SVG and EMF file formats retain the vector drawing -- then import into PowerPoint. Possible downside - PPTX file may be large. However, PowerPoint has incomplete SVG support, and graphics made with the free InskScape program, exported as an EMF file, apparently work better, according to Microsoft Support!

Set higher resolution in the PNG file export in Visio.



I followed the advice of @DrMoishe Pippik.
When I save as EMF the image is not properly transparent. Certain shapes still had bits of color. Maybe there are other settings I need to make in Visio before exporting the image.
I tried exporting the image as PNG with a custom resolution of 400x400 pixels / in and Size set to "Source" and the results are WAY better.
However, in the end I actually remade my image in Canva which was far easier to use than Visio and did a perfect job of exporting the image with a fully transparent backgound that looks good in Powerpoint.
